# ckeditor disappears while refreshing div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have two pages called openclosediv.php and content.php. In openclosediv.php page I have list of records and a button(show/hide div button) which brings content.php into the  that's placed in openclosediv.php . In content.php page I have a ckeditor whenever I click the button, told above, the first time ckeditor appears however, after the first time whenever I push the button ckeditor does not appear.

Here is the code which shows/hides the div in openclosediv.php :

```
    function ShowHideDiv(divid)
    {   

   var block=document.getElementById(divid).style.display;
   if(block=="none")
   {
    document.getElementById(divid).style.display="block";
   }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById(divid).style.display="none";
   }
   var data="divid="+divid;
   jQuery('#'+divid).showLoading();
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "content.php",
           data: data,
           error: function(){
           alert('Error while loading!');
         },
          success: function(data){
            jQuery('#'+divid).hideLoading();
    $('#'+divid).html(data);
     }
     });
   }
```

And here how I creat ckeditor in content.php:

```
                $ckeditor = new CKEditor();
                $ckeditor->basePath  = 'ckeditor/' ;
                CKFinder::SetupCKEditor( $ckeditor, 'ckfinder/' ) ;
                $config['height'] = '300';
        $config['width'] = '700';
                $initialValue = "";
                $ckeditor->editor("somename", $initialValue, $config);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use the `.toggle()` method instead of manually showing and hiding:

```
function ShowHideDiv(divid)
{
    $('#' + divid).toggle();

    // Do ajax
}
```

The `.toggle()` code should replace this piece:

```
var block=document.getElementById(divid).style.display;
if(block=="none")
{
   document.getElementById(divid).style.display="block";
}
else
{
   document.getElementById(divid).style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am doing some database processing in content.php page. Will it still work if I write .toggle(); And  should I place it to the line in which I placed $('#'+divid).html(data);

Comment: See my edit above. This javascript is being executed client-side so what you are doing on the server happens before this ever occurs.

Comment: instead of the part you mentioned I put $("#"+divid).toggle(); however, it did not work again.